# `npm install` with caret semver not getting version updates

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

In the [`package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/package.json#L32) of `react-relay`, we see `"fbjs": "^0.5.1"`. The [latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbjs) of `fbjs` as of this writing is `0.6.1`. However when I `npm install` in my Relay app, I end up getting `fbjs@0.5.1`. By my understanding, the usage of the `^` semver in this case should install all versions up to but not including `1.0.0`. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 4):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-1-2-3-0-2-5-0-0-4

> Caret ranges
>
> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple.
>
> Many authors treat a 0.x version as if the x were the major "breaking-change" indicator.

`^0.5.1` means `>= 0.5.0 < 0.6.0`

Comment: so if "left-most non-zero" part is very important here. Things would be different if `^1.5.1` was used, which would resolve to `>= 1.5.0 < 2`